# react-query mutation not entering in side-effect states onSuccess/onError/onSettled

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have following mutation:

```
export const useRegisterUserMutation = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (data: SignedMessageType) => {
      return UserServiceInstance.register(data);
    },
  });
};
```

and when i use it:

```
mutation.mutate(
          { message, signature },
          {
            onError: (err: any) => {
              console.log('onError: ', err);
              if (err.message === 'User exists') {
                // showModal(MODAL_TYPES.USER_INFORMATION);
                // return router.push(DefinedRoutes.Home);
              }

              // TODO: Handle error
            },
            onSuccess: (resp) => {
              console.log('onSuccess');
              showModal(MODAL_TYPES.USER_INFORMATION);
            },
            onSettled: (data, error, variables, context) => {
              console.log(data, error);
            },
          },
```

never enter in error or any other state what could be wrong?

Also can confirm that error is throwed from the service

further more i can see error catched by react-query

[image: RQ Error]

but for some reason never enter in `onError` state

Answer (score 0):

Better to register onError, onSuccess and onSettled on the useMutation options itself.

```js
export const useRegisterUserMutation = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (data: SignedMessageType) => {
      return UserServiceInstance.register(data);
    },
    onError: (err: any) => {
      console.log('onError: ', err);
      if (err.message === 'User exists') {
                // showModal(MODAL_TYPES.USER_INFORMATION);
                // return router.push(DefinedRoutes.Home);
       }
        // TODO: Handle error
       },
    onSuccess: (resp) => {
      console.log('onSuccess');
                        showModal(MODAL_TYPES.USER_INFORMATION);
    },
    onSettled: (data, error, variables, context) => {
      console.log(data, error);
    },
  });
};
```